# How to disable service worker for sub domains?

Tags: javascript, angular, service-worker, angular-service-worker

I have a webapp that is running with angular and it has a running service worker. Whenever I perform a PUT and GET operations on s3.amazonaws.com the request is always made from a service worker.

What configuration can use to make my request that is going to and from s3.amazonaws.com to be ignored by service worker?

Here is my nsgw-config.json

```
{
  "index": "/index.html",
  "assetGroups": [
    {
      "name": "app",
      "installMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/favicon.ico",
          "/index.html",
          "/*.css",
          "/*.js"
        ]
      }
    }, {
      "name": "assets",
      "installMode": "lazy",
      "updateMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/assets/**"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to prevent duplicate service worker call then please do few steps as below.

1. build your project production mode.
2. goto build folder (default is /dist)
3. open ngsw-worker.js file under /dist directory.
4. find  `onFetch(event) {` function
5. modify the onfetch function like below

   ```
   onFetch(event) {
   ```

   `/* sub domain URL here  and subdomain ajax all domain here.*/`

   ```
   var blackListDomain=["www.xyz.com/api","www.abc.com/v2/api"];

   for (var i = 0; i < blackListDomain.length; i++) {
       if (event.request.url.indexOf(blackListDomain[i])>-1) {
            console.log("revent " + event.request.url);
           return;
       }
   }
   ```

**Hint**

[image]